# React does not recognize the `controlID` prop on a DOM element (React-Bootstrap Forms)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

When creating a form using React components from `react-bootstrap`, and using [code direct from an example](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/forms/#forms) in its docs:

```
  <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
    <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
    <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="Enter email" />
    <Form.Text className="text-muted">
      We'll never share your email with anyone else.
    </Form.Text>
  </Form.Group>
```

gives the following error in the browser JS console:

> React does not recognize the `controlID` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `controlid` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.

Is it possible to avoid this error message while still using the control id feature of React Bootstrap? These error messages stopped appearing after removing `controlId` properties from all the components.

Using

- `bootstrap` 4.4.1
- `react-bootstrap` 1.0.0
- `react-dom` 16.13.1
- `react` 16.13.1
- Node 13.7.0

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work just fine, maybe the problem is not in this part of the code

```js
const {Form} = ReactBootstrap;

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
      <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
      <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="Enter email" />
      <Form.Text className="text-muted">
        We'll never share your email with anyone else.
      </Form.Text>
    </Form.Group>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>

<script
  src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"
  crossorigin
></script>

<script
  src="https://unpkg.com/react-bootstrap@next/dist/react-bootstrap.min.js"
  crossorigin
></script>


<div id="app"></div>
```